# Prompt box showing again and again with blank value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written code in javascript to get the value from promptbox in URL and document but it always printing blank value and promptbox is coming again and again
Any help will be appriciated!

```js
//alert("4");
var name= prompt("Enter your name & see the magic");
if(name!=null && name!=""){
    //alert("1");
    window.location.href = '?n=&m='+name;
    //alert("2");
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = name 
    //alert("3");
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo2"></h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be because the page is always reloading after you submit the name and change the window location. Every time you load the page on the browser, the page state is reset

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are running prompt on page load. Anytime a user enters inside the prompt, the page is refreshed followed by showing up of the prompt. To avoid, check if you have name param set in the url. If it is, do not show the prompt